# Nuget adding same package which is already existing in application

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have three projects namely, `Core`, `Feature1` & `Feature2`. `Feature1&2` both have a project reference to `Core`.

When I `pack` `Feature1` and add that `Nuget` to my application, I am able to see, `Feature1` and underneath see `Core` also.

Similarly, when I pack `Feature2`, It also shows me `Core` under it. Now I have two duplicate `Core` packages.

If I pack `Core`, add it to my application and then pack `Feature1` & `Feature2`, Now I see three `Core` `Nugets` within my application.

My question is: Is there a way, my `Feature1` and `Feature2` check if Core already exists in the application and only then decide to add it to my application? Like a dependent `Nuget` and avoid duplicity?

Is there some configuration I need to do in my `Feature1/2.csproj`?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: "Now I have two duplicate Core packages" - no, you have two dependencies on Core. That's absolutely fine. The Core DLLs won't actually be included in your Feature1 and Feature2 packages, unless you've done that yourself. What do you see in your application after building it? I'd expect to see just one copy of the Core DLL.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added a screen grab. Nothing happens after I build it

Comment: Those listings are just for _informational purposes_ only. Only one reference is added. You can open the project file in a notepad and check.

Comment: It would have been useful to mention that this is a Xamarin project earlier. But fundamentally I expect the same result. Do you have any evidence that there's any actual duplication going on? Are you experiencing any *problems*?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Apologies for not mentioning Xamarin. No I am not experiencing any problems as such, but ideally I think it shouldn't show out all of its referenced projects. If you look at Microsoft's AppCentre.Analytics Nuget, It doesn't show AppCenter(the core project) within it. I'm also worried that it may lead to unnecessary increase in the app size.

Comment: I don't know which exact NuGet package you're referring to there, as AppCentre.Analytics isn't a NuGet package on nuget.org. But your concern over "unnecessary increase in the app size" is precisely why I suggested that you look at the result for the built application. I'm sure you'll only see one copy of Core.

Comment: @MatJ - Thank you, Yes, I do see just one `Core`. I'm guessing that when I actually publish these packages, I will no longer see them like this?

Comment: Assuming you mean `Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics`, I *would* expect to see the dependency on Microsoft.AppCenter in there... and adding a reference to it in my own project (non-Xamarin) I see the dependency as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwYyv.png

Comment: And no, I *would* expect you to see the packages like this, because it's showing you the dependencies. It's a *good* thing to know what each package also depends on.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet. I think I understand now and I think I'm doing it right, just that I've never built a Nuget before. Thanks!!